# SegFault when delete []

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am working on a class for an existing main program, and it is throwing a segfault on the `delete []` line.  I am not quite sure why it is doing this.  I have asked the professor and I was told to reread the section about how pointers get corrupted. Any help would be appreciated! The relevant code is below.

From the main:

```
Point* v = new Point[nVertices];
for (int i = 0; i < nVertices; ++i)
  in >> v[i].x >> v[i].y;
Asteroid aster1 (nVertices, v);
delete [] v;
```

The class section for asteroid's constructor:

```
Asteroid::Asteroid(int nVertices, Point vertexPoints[]){
    numVertices = nVertices;
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++){
        vertices[i] = vertexPoints[i];
    }
}
```

And the .h section if that is significant:

```
class Asteroid{
    int numVertices;
    Point vertices[];
public:
    //Attributes
    Asteroid (int,Point*);
```

Comment: No memory was allocated for `Asteroid::vertices`. Also, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Other than for morbid curiosity, you shouldn't be using pointers, `new` and `delete` at all.

Comment: What's `in`? Do you mean `std::cin`?

Comment: I would rather suspect the segfault is caused by `Asteroid::vertices` being uninitialized in the constructor. Anyway, just use `std::vector` and these problems will go away.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, KerrekSB: Unfortunately students are often forced to use C++ style from 20 years ago :-S

Comment: Students are taught how to use pointers, new and delete because in a classroom you learn things. These are parts of the language that you will see constantly and you need to know how they work.

Comment: Yes, I cannot change to the vector class, I am stuck with the array.  In is (istream& in).  I have a seperate function in the class that prints out the information and it works if I insert it before the delete.  Everything runs on the step through right until the delete line which throws a segfault.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa: Depends on what level they're on. If this is a C++ class for total beginners, they shouldn't even be talking about pointers or `new` or `delete`

Comment: If it's a class for total beginners they shouldn't be learning C++ in the first place.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa: My university teaches C++ as the first programming language for engineers, and they don't cover pointers or `new` or `delete` in the first quarter, but actually proper modern C++. You act as though beginners are completely incapable of learning how to use a language properly.

Comment: How do I go about allocating memory to Asteroid::vertices?  I thought that when I passed it it was allocating...

Comment: When you say "we don't teach them core elements of the language" and then follow it up with "you're acting like they can't learn the language" it seems as if I don't even have to respond in order to make my point. If you want to teach C++ with no memory management, teach Java. There's no such thing as "modern C++" in industry. C++ is only used when you want those features.

Comment: DangerMoose, the problem is that you're passing a pointer to an array and then assigning the values from that array to another array. But the array you're assigning them to hasn't been initialized. It doesn't have any memory associated with it. If you start using pointer arithmetic on it and assigning values, you're overwriting bits of memory that might be in use.

Comment: I think there are many other programming languages that are both easier to understand and would be better for when I get into the real world... however, they are teaching C++.  Where in the program is it appropriate to initialize the array?

Comment: The lessons you learn from learning C++ will be valuable to you in the long run. And anyway, C++ is still used in many places. But over time it will become less common. If you want to copy the Point array you will essentially need to do what you did for the first array. At the beginning of the Asteroid constructor, create a new array with the appropriate number of spaces in it. Then you can copy each value from one array to the other.

Comment: I am super confused.  The first part, with the v array is provided and I cannot change (nor did I write it).  My understanding was that it is a pointer to a dynamic array.  I thought that by calling the constructor that I was passing the data stored on the heap into a permanent array.  If not, is there a way to do this so that I can safely delete the v array?

Comment: When you pass v to the constructor, you're passing a pointer. You are trying to tell me that you wrote the Asteroid constructor, correct? Look at the place where v is created. v is a pointer to the first element of the array. The "new" operator gives you a block of memory for the contents of the array. An array is just contiguous data. You need to allocate some memory for the contents of the array. That's what is being done for v and it's what you need to do for vertices. Right now, vertices is just a bad pointer. It doesn't represent any data.

Comment: I tried putting in a declaration: Point vertices[numVertices]; now my printout just reads out gibberish...  Gibberish being just random memory.

Comment: If you write "Point vertices[numVertices];" inside the constructor, you're creating another array with the same name as your member variable called vertices. That array will disappear when you leave the scope of the constructor. You want to assign the memory to the vertices member variable. I think you'll solve the problem. But I should probably let you do it on your own now.

Comment: Got it!  Added "vertices = new Point[numVertices];" and changed vertices to be a pointer.  Now I can delete the original pointer all I want and still access.  Starting to make a little bit of sense.  (Just a little!) :)  Thanks again for your help, and I still don't like C++.  =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks very unlikely that the segfault is at the `delete[]` line. Much more likely that it occurs in the `Asteroid` constructor, as you are already attempting to access vertices before you've created the array which is supposed to contain them.

Comment: Where would I go about initializing the array then?  I thought that it was created when I did the pass to the constructor using the data that the pointer v was pointing to.

Comment: You would do that right *before* you assign values to its contents. So something like `vertices = new Point[nVertices];` in the constructor before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was wrong but this is what I think user268396 means.

```
class Asteroid{  
    int numVertices;  
    Point* vertices;  // change vertices to be a pointer.
public:  
    //Attributes  
    Asteroid (int,Point*);
```

and your constructor should have the following:

```
Asteroid::Asteroid(int nVertices, Point vertexPoints[]){ 
    numVertices = nVertices; 
    // Allocate array here. You should also you should add a delete[] in the destructor.
    vertices = new Point[numVertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++){ 
        vertices[i] = vertexPoints[i]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I thought that the pointer (v) was just a pointer to a dynamic array.  When I called the constructor I thought that I was copying all of the data that it pointed to into a new array (not referenced by a pointer)... sorry if this sounds confusing, it is because I am confused! :)

Comment: I can understand that as I got mixed up myself. user268396 is correct you need to initialize your vertices before assigning to them.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `delete []` is not where your program is going bad.

Where are you initializing `vertices` in your `Asteroid` class?  All I see is a declaration of a zero sized array (which should probably issue a warning depending on your compiler).

How about forgetting the arrays entirely and using `vector<T>`'s?  That, or declare `vertices` as a pointer and initialize it properly.